# Alternative for old Springframework util.Assert?

Tags: java, spring, validation

While I was just about to use an old class that is about 2 years old I realized it used the old Springframework. The new framework is rather hard to navigate, and I don't need it for anything else.

The class is a nice implementation of strtotime (AKA String to Time). https://github.com/collegeman/stringtotime/blob/master/src/main/java/com/clutch/dates/StringToTime.java

Of course when I go to compile all I get is this: `NoClassDefFoundError occured : org/springframework/util/Assert` and even when I try including an old spring jar it makes no difference.

The only part of the class depending on it is the .util.Assert:

```
Assert.notNull(dateTimeString);
Assert.notNull(now);
Assert.notNull(simpleDateFormat);
```

Is anyone aware of the following:

- A link to the Assert source (can't find it via Google)
- A substitute library
- A better class just like StringToTime

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Guava's Preconditions](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html). [google-guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) is an excellent addition to your application.

`Preconditions.checkNotNull` is what you need. There are overloaded versions that allow you to specify the error message etc.

Comment: Looks like this will do the trick. Will report back in 10 min thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

- [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) [`Validate`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html)
- [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`Preconditions`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html)

[Here's an article](http://piotrjagielski.com/blog/google-guava-vs-apache-commons-for-argument-validation/) comparing them.

Comment: +1 for the comparison, however looks like guava is the best implementation for my situation. thanks!